# Как открыть расширение браузера через python+selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Задача: Мне нужен чтоб открыл расширение а точнее кликнули и работал с расширением. Расширение открывает новое веб окно с помощью селениума нельзя, а с чем можно? Этот фрагмент кода запускает расширение вместе с браузером теперь надо чтоб он открыл расширение чтоб работать с ним в долнейшем. А расширение открывает новое окно как браузер

код выглядит так:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
 
#Расширение браузер
#-----------------------------------------------------
chop = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chop.add_extension("D:\Backup\Python\extension_1_0_5_0.crx")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chop)
#-----------------------------------------------------
```